# Where do sagemaker project templates deployment get the environment variables from

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-codebuild

I have downloaded a sagemaker project template in sagemaker studio. The one I have downloaded is **MLOps template for model building, training, and deployment**. (See documentation on it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-projects-templates-sm.html#sagemaker-projects-templates-code-commit) and the code that gets downloaded [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-secure-mlops/tree/98e37cc47dba80608c30f6dd4e8edad6656eb037/mlops-seed-code)).

I am confused where the enviroment variables are set for deployment. You can see these referenced in deployment in the `buildspec.yml` code build file. (See the file [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-secure-mlops/blob/98e37cc47dba80608c30f6dd4e8edad6656eb037/mlops-seed-code/model-deploy/buildspec.yml))

```
python build.py \
          --sagemaker-project-id "$SAGEMAKER_PROJECT_ID" --sagemaker-project-name "$SAGEMAKER_PROJECT_NAME" \
          --model-package-group-name "$SOURCE_MODEL_PACKAGE_GROUP_NAME" \
          --staging-config-name "$STAGING_CONFIG_NAME" --prod-config-name "$PROD_CONFIG_NAME" \
          --sagemaker-execution-role-staging-name "$SAGEMAKER_EXECUTION_ROLE_STAGING_NAME" \
          --sagemaker-execution-role-prod-name "$SAGEMAKER_EXECUTION_ROLE_PROD_NAME" \
          --staging-accounts "$STAGING_ACCOUNT_LIST" \
          --prod-accounts "$PROD_ACCOUNT_LIST" \
          --env-name "$ENV_NAME" \
          --ebs-kms-key-arn "$SAGEMAKER_EBS_KMS_KEY_ARN" \
          --env-type-staging-name "$ENV_TYPE_STAGING_NAME" \
          --env-type-prod-name "$ENV_TYPE_PROD_NAME" \
          --multi-account-deployment "$MULTI_ACCOUNT_DEPLOYMENT"
```

However, I cannot see where these enviroment variables are set. For example, where is `SOURCE_MODEL_PACKAGE_GROUP_NAME` set?

Answer (score 0):

These variables are set in the CloudFormation template that defines the CodePipeline and CodeBuild.

This is probably the one you're looking for:

- https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-secure-mlops/blob/master/cfn_templates/project-model-deploy.yaml#L226

If you deployed your SageMaker Project through SageMaker Studio, you should already have a CloudFormation stack which you could update.